# Anything similar to onPostExecute for IntentService?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I'm trying to move from an AsyncTask in an activity to an IntentService.  My main goal is to keep as much out of the activity as possible so the service can easily be triggered from different places in the application without relying on an activity to handle the results.

In an AsyncTask I'd use onPostExecute to handle the result after all the heavy lifting was done, but this doesn't seem to exist for IntentService.  I hate the idea of using a ResultReceiver because I then have to parcel up the resulting data, forcing the main thread to then handle deserializing it.  Is there any other alternative I'm missing other than then turning around and having the ResultReceiver use an AsyncTask to deserialize the results?

Thanks!

**Update**

I couldn't come up with anything better, so I ended up using a ResultReceiver.  My service returns primitive data (a string) to the receiver, which then parses the string and creates Java objects.  My receiver calls back to my activity with the strongly-typed objects.  It works great, but it definitely feels clunky having to use a service, receiver, and internal receiver callbacks class.

Comment: you can call asycntask from onstart method

Answer (score 0):

In an Asynctask, onPostExecute runs on UI thread. So if your intention is to do the main work off the UI thread, processing the result on onPostExecute won't help. 
In you case you can do the heavy lifting like deserializing in the background thread itself. 
If its a webservice call, do the service call and result processing in the same service thread.

Comment: But with AsyncTask, you can pass back regular data to the onPostExecute.  My impression of IntentService is you have to put parcelable data on a Bundle, thus forcing the handler to convert that data to its final form.  I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing, or if I just need to then turn around and use an AsyncTask's doInBackground inside a ResultReceiver to parse that data (since I don't want it run on the main thread.)  I was hoping to do everything in IntentActivity but it's looking like I have to split it between that and the ResultReceiver.  Hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this yourself using a `Handler` tied to the main thread. A `Handler` [is tied to the thread that creates it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler()). Hence, by creating the `Handler` in a block of code that is invoked by the main thread, e.g. as part of `onCreate()`, you have a hook into the main thread job list. Now, at the very end of your `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` implementation, you simply post the set of statements that you want to run on the main thread to the `Handler` instance.

Example code:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author Janus Varmarken (varmarken@gmail.com).
 */
public class ExampleIntentService extends IntentService {

    // Handler tied to the main thread.
    private Handler mHandler;

    public ExampleIntentService() {
        super(ExampleIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Make sure to call super such that IntentService can properly manage its lifecycle
        // (it needs to create a background thread and manage a job list for this thread)
        super.onCreate();

        // As onCreate is run on the main thread, we can tie a Handler to the main thread by
        // creating it here.
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Do heavy lifting here...
        // Here we just sleep for the sake of the example.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // When heavy lifting is done:
        // Create a runnable containing the statements you want to run on the main/UI thread.
        Runnable uithreadStatements = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // main/UI thread statements goes here.
                Toast.makeText(ExampleIntentService.this, "Toasting on main thread.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        // Post the job to the handler instance which is tied to the main thread
        // so that the job will be executed on the main/UI thread.
        mHandler.post(uithreadStatements);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always broadcast intent in `onHandleIntent` and receive it in `BroadcastReceiver`. `OnReceive`from `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main thread.